# How do i properly require a referenced project file

Tags: typescript, monorepo

I have a monorepo with this hierarchy:

```
root
    server
        tsconfig.json
    shared
        tsconfig.json
```

(they both have their src / dst folders)

In *server* I am trying to import a script from shared using a relative path

```
import PlayerModel from "../../../../shared/src/entities/playerModel"
```

After transpiling with tsc (first on shared, then on server), the import path doesnt change:

```
var playerModel_1 = require("../../../../shared/src/entities/playerModel");
```

After running the server, it results in error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../../../shared/src/entities/playerModel'
```

There are tsconfig.json files:

**shared**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dst/",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,

    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

**server**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dst/",
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,

        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "references": [{
        "path": "../shared"
    }]
}
```

Comment: does `import { PlayerModel } from '../../../../shared/src/entities/playerModel` work?

Comment: Throws an error, since PlayerModel has a default export of a class.
I removed the default keyword and did it by importing by { } and it still didnt change the import path (resulting in the same import error when running the server).

One thing to note is that it doesn't throw any errors in ide (vscode with typescript extensions)